# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{4^n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

Why is

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{4^n}=0\text{ ?}$$

Having a hard time proving this one with the definitions of the limit of a sequence. I'm trying to apply Bernoulli's inequality to $2^n$ to make it easier for myself but I'm completely lost.

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive.

Comment: By "definitions of the limit", do you mean epsilon-delta?

Comment: Are you allowed to use ratio test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some $N \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$
\frac{n}{4^{n}} = \frac{n}{2^{2n}} < \frac{n}{2^{n}} \leq \frac{n}{n^{2}} = \frac{1}{n};
$$
if $\varepsilon > 0$, then $n \geq \lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \rceil + 1$ only if $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$;  therefore, if $n \geq \max \{ N, \lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \rceil + 1 \}$, then $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: so as n approaches 0, then 1/n = 0?

Comment: Well, you could say that; but to articulate it please see my revised answer.

Comment: $n^2>2^n$ for $n=3$.  So, suggest you modify the "$n\ge1$" qualification.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks; forgot to do so.

Comment: @user270494 Do you get it now?

Comment: @GudsonChou Yes thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By the Bernoulli Inequality, we have $2^n\ge 1+n$ for every positive integer $n$, and therefore $4^n=2^n\cdot 2^n\ge (1+n)^2$. Thus if $n\ge 1$, then
$$\frac{n}{4^n}\le \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}\lt \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}.$$
Now producing, for given $\epsilon\gt 0$,  an appropriate $N$ should not be difficult.